# f# - Use common object without passing it everywhere

Tags: compilation, f#

I have function `compile` which takes AST and produces string with assembly instructions. Inside it I create a StringBuilder object. Also inside `compile` there are a lot of local functions like `emitIf`, `emitLet`, etc. 
The reason of defining local functions is that `StringBuilder` object doesn't have to be passed to `emit` functions as additional parameter. But I feel that this solution is somewhat awkward.

```
module Compile
let compile ast =
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
    let emitn s = sb.AppendLine s |> ignore
    let emitfn f = Printf.kprintf emitn f
    let emitLoadNumber (n:int) = 
        emitfn "  mov $%d, %%rax" n

    let rec emitExpr env si =
    //...
    and emitIf isTail env si cond th el =
    //...
```

As another solution, I could create `StringBuilder` in the module scope and also move local function into module scope.

My question is: is there a better way to define a bunch of functions that use common object, like stream or `StringBuilder`, without passing it to each of the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I'd probably define a bunch of functions in the module that take an explicit StringBuilder parameter, and then use partial application to define a bunch of local functions that close over one specific StringBuilder instance. E.g.,

```
module Compile

let emitn sb s = sb.AppendLine s |> ignore
let emitfn sb f = Printf.kprintf (emitn sb) f
let emitLoadNumber sb (n:int) =
    emitfn sb "  mov $%d, %%rax" n

let compile ast =
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
    let emitn = emitn sb
    let emitfn = emitfn sb
    let emitLoadNumber = emitLoadNumber sb

    let rec emitExpr env si =
    //...
    and emitIf isTail env si cond th el =
    //...
```

Now inside the `compile` function and its subfunctions (`emitExpr`, `emitIf`, and so on) you can use `emitn "foo"` and it will add the string "foo\n" to the StringBuilder instance you created at the start of `compile`. (Which will be a different instance each time you call the function, of course). But you *also* have generally-useful versions of `emitn`, `emitfn`, etc. available, which makes unit-testing FAR easier.

Comment: What I don't like in my solution is that `compile` function gets really big - ~400 lines of code for toy language. Is such a big function normal for F#?

Comment: The `compile` function has so many subfunctions (`emitExpr`, `emitIf`, etc.) that you could almost consider it a module itself. How many lines of code in the `compile` function are *not* function definitions, but are actual logic in `compile` as opposed to being in subfunctions? If the answer is more then 50, then maybe you should be concerned. But if those 400 LoC are because of all the subfunction definitions defined inside the `let compile ast = ...` block, then I wouldn't worry about it.